# how can I rotate the text in a Table?

Tags: rotation, itext

I use iText for .NET v 4.1.2.0

My table (iTextSharp.text.Table) has many columns. I want the text in the cell housed vertically. This possibility is in the cells PdfPTable, but I can not use it

```
pdfPCell.Rotation = 90;
```

How I can rotate text in cells of Table?

Comment: Why can't you use PdfPCell.Rotation?

Comment: For use pdfpTable fails to set header on each new page (Method EndHeaders() )